# Flex & PHP - Insert Query in Php Service

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a MySql DB with 2 tables:
1. category - categoryID / category / description
2. photos - photoID / categoryID / photodescription / photo

And i have a service (CategoryService.php) automatically created by Flash Builder, but i cannot get the second table!!

```
    <?php

class CategoryService {

    var $username = "root";
    var $password = "";
    var $server = "localhost";
    var $port = "3306";
    var $databasename = "teste";
    var $tablename = "category";

    var $connection;

    /**
     * The constructor initializes the connection to database. Everytime a request is 
     * received by Zend AMF, an instance of the service class is created and then the
     * requested method is invoked.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(
                                $this->server,  
                                $this->username,  
                                $this->password, 
                                $this->databasename,
                                $this->port
                            );

        $this->throwExceptionOnError($this->connection);
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the rows from the table.
     *
     * Add authroization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllCategory() {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename");        
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        $rows = array();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->categoryId, $row->category, $row->description);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
          $rows[] = $row;
          $row = new stdClass();
          mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->categoryId, $row->category, $row->description);
        }

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
        mysqli_close($this->connection);

        return $rows;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the item corresponding to the value specified for the primary key.
     *
     * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
     *
     * 
     * @return stdClass
     */
    public function getCategoryByID($itemID) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename where categoryId=?");
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $itemID);        
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->categoryId, $row->category, $row->description);

        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
          return $row;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the item corresponding to the value specified for the primary key.
     *
     * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
     *
     * 
     * @return stdClass
     */
    public function createCategory($item) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "INSERT INTO $this->tablename (category, description) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $item->category, $item->description);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        $autoid = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
        mysqli_close($this->connection);

        return $autoid;
    }

    /**
     * Updates the passed item in the table.
     *
     * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
     *
     * @param stdClass $item
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateCategory($item) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "UPDATE $this->tablename SET category=?, description=? WHERE categoryId=?");      
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssi', $item->category, $item->description, $item->categoryId);       
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the item corresponding to the passed primary key value from 
     * the table.
     *
     * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
     *
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleteCategory($itemID) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "DELETE FROM $this->tablename WHERE categoryId = ?");
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $itemID);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }


    /**
     * Returns the number of rows in the table.
     *
     * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
     *
     * 
     */
    public function count() {
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM $this->tablename");
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $rec_count);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
        mysqli_close($this->connection);

        return $rec_count;
    }


    /**
     * Returns $numItems rows starting from the $startIndex row from the 
     * table.
     *
     * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
     *
     * 
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCategory_paged($startIndex, $numItems) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename LIMIT ?, ?");
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $startIndex, $numItems);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        $rows = array();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->categoryId, $row->category, $row->description);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
          $rows[] = $row;
          $row = new stdClass();
          mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->categoryId, $row->category, $row->description);
        }

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
        mysqli_close($this->connection);

        return $rows;
    }


    /**
     * Utility function to throw an exception if an error occurs 
     * while running a mysql command.
     */
    private function throwExceptionOnError($link = null) {
        if($link == null) {
            $link = $this->connection;
        }
        if(mysqli_error($link)) {
            $msg = mysqli_errno($link) . ": " . mysqli_error($link);
            throw new Exception('MySQL Error - '. $msg);
        }       
    }
}

?>
```

In Flash Builder i have 2 spark List, the first one have all categorys and i want when `selectedItem` it populates the other one with the correspondent photos.
I have a query that works with the database but i cannot insert it into php.
This is the query:

```
SELECT TC.*, TP.photodescription , TP.photo FROM category TC inner join photos TP on TC.categoryId = TP.categoryId
```

How can i do this!?
Hope it's understandable, thanks for "listening".

EDIT:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        protected function list_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getAllCategoryResult.token = categoryService.getAllCategory();
        }


        protected function list2_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getAllphotosResult.token = photosService.getAllphotos();
        }

        protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            category = list.selectedItem;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getAllCategoryResult"/>
    <categoryservice:CategoryService id="categoryService"
                                     fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                     showBusyCursor="true"/>
    <valueObjects:Category id="category"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="getAllphotosResult"/>
    <photosservice:photosService id="photosService"
                                   fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                   showBusyCursor="true"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:List id="list" x="197" y="127" creationComplete="list_creationCompleteHandler(event)" change="list_changeHandler(event)"
        labelField="category">
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllCategoryResult.lastResult}"/>
</s:List>
<s:List id="list2" x="708" y="127" creationComplete="list2_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
        labelField="photo">
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllphotosResult.lastResult}"/>
</s:List>
```

This is an example of my .mxml.
          How can i on "selectedItem" change the second List based on the categoryId!?
    Could you please help or show me some examples!?
     Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

FLashBuilder created a CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) class for you. This is only based on your one category table. `var $tablename = "category";` - thus it only returns results for category. If you want to do a JOIN then you have a few choices:

1. Custom write a new method in the generated class with your JOIN statement, remove the class from your FlashBuilder project, and import the updated file into FlashBuilder as an existing PHP class.
2. Create a second generated PHP class for the photo table and then join the results within your Flex application.
3. Use the Merge fields option for a JOIN operation that returns data retrieved from multiple database tables. (probably the best option)

To learn more about how to do this, see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WSbde04e3d3e6474c4-668f02f4120d422cf08-7ff7.html

Comment: thanks a lot for the whole explanation!! I really tried but i'm not achieving that..

Comment: I edit the post with my .mxml. Hope you can help me. Thanks again.